# How to extract text within HTML lists using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a python program that can extract text between list in html. I would like to extract information like the book being hardcover and number of pages. Does anybody know the command for this operation?

```
<h2>Product Details</h2>
  <div class="content">
<ul>

<li><b>Hardcover:</b> 156 pages</li>

<li><b>Publisher:</b> Insight Editions; Har/Pstr edition (June 18, 2013)</li>

<li><b>Language:</b> English</li>

<li><b>ISBN-10:</b> 1608871827</li>
<li><b>ISBN-13:</b> 978-1608871827</li>
```

For parse other information I used:

```
definition in soup.findAll('span', {"class":'bb_price'}):
definition = definition.renderContents()
```

but it does not work for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `b` tag by [`text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) and get the [`next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling).

Working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<h2>Product Details</h2>
  <div class="content">
<ul>

<li><b>Hardcover:</b> 156 pages</li>

<li><b>Publisher:</b> Insight Editions; Har/Pstr edition (June 18, 2013)</li>

<li><b>Language:</b> English</li>

<li><b>ISBN-10:</b> 1608871827</li>
<li><b>ISBN-13:</b> 978-1608871827</li></ul></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

print soup.find('b', text='Hardcover:').next_sibling
print soup.find('b', text='Publisher:').next_sibling
```

prints:

```
156 pages
Insight Editions; Har/Pstr edition (June 18, 2013)
```