# Capture text between list tags and print from BeautifulSoup scrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Just getting started with Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup and Requests. 
I'm trying to create a script that could scrape messages on an ordered list [here](https://www.serenataflowers.com/pollennation/love-text-messages/)

I'm stuck on how to print line 2 of the messages listed [there](https://www.serenataflowers.com/pollennation/love-text-messages/)

This is the script i have so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

res = requests.get("https://www.serenataflowers.com/pollennation/love-text-messages/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')  

ol = soup.find('ol') 
print(ol.prettify())
```

The script only prints out the entire text. How do i go about printing out Text 2 or text 3 and so on...

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the result i get when i run the script.

C:\Users\XXXX\MyPythonScripts>scrape.py

```
<ol class="simple-list">
 <li>
  Meeting you was the best day of my life.
 </li>
 <li>
  When you are next to me, or when we are apart, You are always the first in my thoughts and in my heart.
 </li>
 <li>
  I never ever thought I’d like you this much and I never planned to have you on my mind this often.
 </li>
 <li>
  I love the way you love me.
 </li>
 <li>
  Spring drops and the sun outside the window tell me that this spring will be the flowering of our love.
 </li>
 <li>
  I can’t spend a day without you, can’t you see? I love you so much. You are a part of me and this is forever.
 </li>
 <li>
  You make me happy in a thousand ways. I love you to the moon and back, and I have no idea what I would do, if I lost you, because I feel like I will lose my entire world.
 </li>
 <li>
  Nothing is going change my love for you, you are the man, who helped me to find myself in this life.
 </li>
 <li>
  I can’t imagine living a life without you. You are my reason to be.
 </li>
 <li>
  The wind whispers your name, stars illuminate my way to you, we will meet soon, love you!
 </li>
```

I was actually looking to print out the next content(s) on the `<li>` tag.

Comment: Can you edit and add an example of the text you are getting out now, and the text you are wanting to get?

Comment: Edited. You can check now.

Comment: So the output you want is only the text and not the html tag portion in a list or something?

Comment: Yes! And i also want to understand how to print the next line of the messages without the <li> tag.

Comment: Try looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23303194/10366273)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a faster class selector to get the parent ol and then nth-of-type to isolate particular lines:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r  = requests.get('https://www.serenataflowers.com/pollennation/love-text-messages/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
line_number = 2
print(soup.select_one(f'.simple-list li:nth-of-type({line_number})').text)
```

Indexing off entire list would be faster if wanting all lines at some point but worth knowing about [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) and [related tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/).

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the text in each quote use the `findAll()` method on the `ol` block that you have already isolated.

```py
ol = soup.find('ol') 
messages = [msg.text for msg in ol.findAll('li')]  # this goes through and isolates the text of each message
```

Now you can access the messages by their index. Remember that lists are 0 indexed, meaning item 1 is actually = 0.

```py
print(messages[0]) # Actually the first message
# output: Meeting you was the best day of my life.
```

Comment: Worked!  Can you please explain how you were able to find an answer to that loop?

Comment: Is there any part of it in particular you are confused about?

Answer (score 0):

Try using find_all to get a list of results. find just returns the first thing it finds. Try find all on li

Comment: Yes even when i find or find_all, it gives me the same result. I'm actually looking for a way to print out the next item on the <li> tags. I have made an edit to the question you can check for my result.